# Error when creating frontend project in Vite using yarn command

Tags: npm, frontend, vite, yarn-v2

I'm trying to create a frontend project in Vite, using the yarn create vite command, but I'm getting the following error:

[image: error with 'yarn create vite']

If I create the project with npm (npm create vite@latest), nothing wrong happens and the project is created successfully, my problem is only when using yarn.
My installed Node version is latest 18.12.1 LTS

I wasn't having this problem, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use images to paste code if it is not strictly necessary
2. Vite requires Node.js version 14.18+, 16+
   https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project
3. Install another version of node with `nvm` https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

   nvm install ***version-number***

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at this thread, but the problem has been resolved. Thank you my friend for your contribution!